# How to access deleted pages on Wikipedia

Tags: wikipedia

I would like to access a page which has been deleted on Wikipedia (e.g. [Junk dna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junk_dna)). When going to that page, it says:

> This page has been deleted. The deletion and move log for the page are provided below for reference.

Therefore, where or how I can access deleted pages?

Comment: When I searched for "Junk DNA" this is what I found: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncoding_DNA#Junk_DNA does this help?

Comment: Thanks, but not really, I'd like to see what was exactly on that removed page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The article [Junk dna](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Junk_dna) was actually deleted, there is no simple way for a non-administrator to view it. If you really want to get its content, you'll have to [contact an administrator to get it for you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Wikipedia_administrators_willing_to_provide_copies_of_deleted_articles).

The article [Junk DNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Junk_DNA) (which is a different article) was *not* deleted. Instead, it was made into a redirect to Noncoding DNA#Junk DNA. If you want to view the redirect page, [click the link in "Redirected from Junk DNA"](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Junk_DNA&redirect=no) below the article title. You can then work with that article as usual, including [viewing its history](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Junk_DNA&action=history), which you can use to access the pre-redirect versions of the article.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if a page has been deleted on Wikipedia (and not merged with another page) you need to have administrator rights to view the contents of the deleted page. Getting these rights is not easy, you can read about the process here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Requests_for_adminship

Answer (score 1):

The page was marge with the page "Noncoding DNA" at this section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncoding_DNA#Junk_DNA

You can confirm it it in Scientizzle (the user who did it) [history](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?limit=500&tagfilter=dna&title=Special%3AContributions&contribs=user&target=Scientizzle&namespace=&tagfilter=&year=2010&month=3) (I already filterd it for you to march 2010, just search: "15:42, 17 March 2010").

You can see at his history (couple of days before and after the 17) he working on "Noncoding DNA". After he work on it he redirect the page, so this is how it [look.](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Junk_DNA&redirect=no) And this is the [diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Junk_DNA&diff=prev&oldid=350415451) from the redirect, you can see there all the stuff he remove. It is in Wikipedia tags (not plain text), but it's the best I can found, Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I've found the deleted [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Junk_DNA&oldid=507678514). It's quite tricky and not user friendly how they hide/delete these pages. Thanks, I did copy of that page.